# How can I sort or filter a dictionary using the highest Int values?

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

I have an array of tuples,

```
var basics = [String: Int]()
basics = ["harry": 89, "chris": 33, "jane": 98, "hans": 90, "finn": 98 ]
```

How can I sort or filter the array to get the tuple(s) with highest value(s), taking into consideration cases that could have more than one, like above where "jane" and "finn" both have 98?

Comment: That's not an array of tuples – that's a dictionary.

Comment: `print(basics.sorted(by: {$0.1 > $1.1}))`

Comment: You should read the language guide. That's a Dictionary.

Comment: Also try [this tutorial](https://www.weheartswift.com/closures/). I recommend trying its other tutorials as well

Comment: what you like to do in the special case of same age? same sort as in basics or by name?

Comment: @Hamish Oops, sorry about that

Comment: @LeoDabus thanks for the edit

Comment: @Containment you are welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could obtain this by sorting and then filtering your list. For this, you'll use some of Swift's standard high-level functions:

```
//define basics
let basics = ["harry": 89, "chris": 33, "jane": 98, "hans": 90, "finn": 98 ]
//sort basics by the age value from highest to lowest
let sortedBasics = basics.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }
//filter the list to remove any elements with a value lower than our recorded high
let filteredBasics = sortedBasics.filter { $1 == sortedBasics.first?.value }
print(filteredBasics) //[("jane", 98), ("finn", 98)]
```

For reference: The `$0` and `$1` are considered "shorthand" names for the inferred parameters of the `filter` and `sorted` functions. Also note that these two functions are not mutating, so `basics` still remains in the same state.

Comment: `.sorted { $0.value > $1.value }`

Comment: Given that you're only interesting in the maximum value, `max(by:)` would be a better choice than `sorted(by:)` – O(n) vs. O(nlog(n)).

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Dictionary where Value : Comparable, Value : Hashable {

    public func maxKeys() -> (max: Value?, keys: [Key]) {
        guard count > 0 else {
            return (nil, [])
        }

        var max: Value = first!.value
        var keys: [Key] = []

        for (key, value) in self {
            if value > max {
                max = value
                keys = [key]
            } else if value == max {
                keys.append(key)
            }
        }

        return (max, keys)
    }

}

let (max, keys) = basics.maxKeys()

print(max!, keys)
// 98 ["jane", "finn"]
```